# Is there a possibility to filter queries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: security, postgresql

I want to limit access to username+password table to one query pattern like:

```
SELECT count(id) AS auth_result
  FROM user
 WHERE username = '%s' 
   AND password = SHA1('%s')
```

(this query doesn't pretend to be working from the point of injection vulnerability, just an example)

Is that possible? or am I missing some different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revoke all access to `user` table from all users except the owner, and create a view with like this:

```
create view auth_view as
select id, username, sha1(password) as sha1pass
  from user;
```

Then your query will look like:

```
select count(id)
  from auth_view
 where username = '%s'
   and sha1pass = sha1('%s')
```

Other possibility might be using [PostgreSQL's rule system](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/rules.html) to rewrite or avoid certain king of queries on `user` table. But I am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want to exclude possibility of dumping the user table with such limited account. The approach with view still allows to dump all usernames and hashed passwords.

Comment: You can write a function then. Your function would receive user/password and return true/false if the user/pass combination matches...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether what you plan is good or not but it should be possible with [rewrite rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createrule.html). Never played with it though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write a function, and make it SECURITY DEFINER. See for example http://www.hagander.net/talks/hidden%20gems%20of%20postgresql.pdf, pages 28-36.